# Why does my multisite blog doesn't show users?

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite install with about 40 blogs. All blogs but one (id=5) works fine.
In this one blog, when trying to access the users list it shows an empty list (header & footer) with the text 6 items below the list footer.

When trying to create a new user on this blog I can see that the roles dropdowns are empty (thus not allowing to create a new user).

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem.
The issue was in wp_options table.
Find line where option name is wp_user_roles and look what's going on there. This line is responsible for user roles, and if they are an a mess, users canot be shown as well.
Better copy option_value from the other table.

(Change wp_ to your prefix).

Comment: Not everyone knows what those roles are supposed to look like. Can you clarify this?

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your Database or Code it's really hard to give you something like a useful solution.

But here go some possibilities:

- Deactivate all the plugins on this blog
- Change the theme

If both of these doesn't work, try checking for the wp_5_options on this blog, I thing it might be a problem with the row with this "option_name" wp_5_user_roles, go to a working blog and copy the contents of this option and past on this one. **Don't forget to backup.**

Hope I could help on something.

Comment: Thanks, already tried all these. It's not a plugin/theme thing (tried changing + all the network uses the same plugins/theme). In the DB there isn't such row on the options table for 4 blogs I've checked (3 working one with problem). any other idea ?

Comment: It must be something on the database, otherwise all the blogs of the network should break on that. I would say to copy this code from this link and then create this row on your wp_5_options, I was checking all of my Blogs have this row. [See mine](http://tinypaste.com/4b34a250)